# Can I roll back this edit to my answer?

Tags: discussion, language, editing

My answer [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/is-there-any-time-when-you-can-use-beaucoup-des/14232#14232) was edited twice to replace the word *sandwiches* with *sandwichs*. However, dictionaries say both spellings are acceptable.

I asked the second person who edited my answer why it had been changed a second time, but didn't receive a reply.

I would like to roll back the answer to my original one, however I am uncertain whether this would be considered appropriate, especially because the second person to edit my answer is a moderator.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware you had already edited your answer. The spelling *sandwiches* is not common anymore and it hardly makes sense both pronunciation-wise and because it comes from a proper name. In my mind it was simply a mistake due the alternation of languagues. Do as you please.

Answer (score 5):

You get primary editorial control to your post in most cases, especially for an answer (for a question, ownership is a bit more diluted because a question's title and tags serve for the whole thread). For something like spelling variants which are formally correct, you definitely get to choose. The edits to change *sandwiches* to *sandwichs* were not appropriate, though excusable as the *sandwiches* spelling is perhaps not universally known¹. Feel free to roll back that edit.

Don't engage in a rollback war — if someone (no matter who) keeps reverting your edit, flag for moderator attention.

¹  <sub>[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sandwich%2C+sandwichs%2C+sandwiches&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csandwich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csandwichs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csandwiches%3B%2Cc0) shows that the -es plural was more common through most of the 20th century, but the regular -s plural has about caught up, and regular plurals for imported words have been systematically correct for a long time, so some people always use them.</sub>